# How to write if and else statement if the statement is not a float in python?

Tags: python, calculation

I'm doing a simple calculation again.

```
import sys

a = float(sys.argv[1])
b = float(sys.argv[2])
c = float(sys.argv[3])
if a == str or  b == str or c == str:
   print 'Your input is invalid'
else:   
    print 'Average: %.2f ' % ((a + b + c) / 3)
```

or

```
import sys

a = float(sys.argv[1])
b = float(sys.argv[2])
c = float(sys.argv[3])
if a != float(sys.argv[1]) or  b =! float(sys.argv[2]r or c =! float(sys.argv[3])
   print 'Your input is invalid'
else:   
    print 'Average: %.2f ' % ((a + b + c) / 3)
```

Comment: Both are bad for floating point comparison because it is inherently imprecise. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: the title declaims **not an integer**, but you are dealing with float, why?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Float is not an integer, so I don't see a contradiction...

Comment: @EugeneSh., there is a contradiction: he expects float, but the title is about integer (and I know float is not an integer, you may not mention that)

Comment: @EugeneSh i dont quite understand with that point

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest my bad buddy, i have changed the title.

Comment: @greatestever There is a link I provided. Have you read it? Update: Well, I guess I mistakengly gave you a way too formal article instead of the simplified one. Let me find it in my bookmarks..

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
try:
    a,b,c = nums = [float(a) for a in sys.argv[1:]]
    print 'Average: %.2f' % (sum(nums)/len(nums)))
except:
    print 'Your input is invalid'
```

Comment: Should be as easy as that.